# Why the rise of the acceleration vs time and velocity vs time graphs of a SHM are less than the rise of the position vs time graph

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, spring

I’m studying Simple Harmonic Motion. Given that the equation of the motion is $x=X_0\cos(\omega t)$ and $v=-\omega X_0\sin(\omega t)$ and $a=-\omega^2X_0\cos(\omega t)$.

As you can see there are more multipliers in front of the velocity and acceleration functions. Then why on earth their graphs have less rise than the position?

[image]

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Will do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x,\,v,\,a$ all have different dimension, the sizes can't be compared. The diagram admits to using "different scales" for the three curves.

Comparing the scales for $x,\,v$ gives a nondimensionalisation for $\omega$; the answer to your question is then that this achieves $\omega<1$.

It's unstated whether the nondimensionalisation of $\omega$ inherent in the $v$-vs-$a$ comparison gives it the same value, but it will if the artist was sensible. (I think they were, since the red amplitude empirically approximates the geometric mean of the other curves' amplitudes.) At any rate, $\omega<1$ is again honoured.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much!